# Batch File: Selecting Multiple Newly Uploaded Files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm having trouble writing a batch file that can count how many new files are added to a folder. This is an overview of the entire system, we have a folder that will receive an encrypted file whenever they trigger an upload. The file can only be received once every hour, and we sometimes receive multiple files at once.

So far, I have created a batch file that could detect only one newly uploaded file and managed to decrypt the encrypted file. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set LAST=%%i
echo newest file: %LAST%

gpg --batch --passphrase="PASSPHRASE" --output "OUTPUT FOLDER%LAST%" --decrypt "%LAST%"
timeout 50
```

So basically, the first line is all about locating the most recently uploaded file based on the parameter I've set up and naming it `"%LAST%"`. The following line is simply a method for decrypting the encrypted file and directing where the output file should be placed.
But the code can only detect one file. How should I make it detect multiple files and only the newly uploaded files? I've been thinking of using for loop and counter, but I'm not sure how to implement that method.

Comment: The whole point of the first line seems to be to get the most recently uploaded file (as you mention). So it would, of course, only detect one file - the most recently created one. It is unclear what you mean by "make it detect multiple files and only the newly uploaded files". Typically, if it is a watch folder, you want to move the file out (maybe to a subfolder) as you process each file. Otherwise, you would need some indicator of what files are processed or not, like maybe changing the file name. Does any of this sound like it would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the processing of each file *within* your `FOR` loop. Something more like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do (
   set LAST=%%i
   echo newest file: !LAST!
   echo gpg --batch --passphrase="PASSPHRASE" --output "OUTPUT FOLDER!LAST!" --decrypt "!LAST!"
   timeout 2
   echo move "!LAST!" c:\already_processed
)
echo All done!
```

I replaced your `gpg` execution with an `echo` of that line, but you get the gist.

Note that within your `FOR` loop, you need to have enabled delayed expansion as shown. (You could also launch `cmd /V:on`, which turns it on for the duration of your CMD session.) As part of that, your variable references will need to use `!variable!` notation with `!` to ensure they have the values of the current iteration.

Finally, I suggest you `move` each file to another directory after it's been processed. Otherwise you're going to have to maintain a list of files that have already been processed, and that seems more cumbersome than just moving them out of the directory.

Comment: This seems like it can work. Correct me if Im wrong, but the for loop will go through every files in the folder right?

Comment: That actually works! Thank you. But there is still a slight problem. Now, whenever I run the batch file, it ask for passphrase eventho I already did wrote it down in the file

Comment: @Stephan yes, I've corrected that in my own code. I changed it to "OUTPUT FOLDER\!LAST!"